# Append to Chef array attribute

Tags: ruby, attributes, chef-infra

I am trying to initialise an empty Chef attribute like so:

`node.default['tool_list'] = Array.new`

and I want to add elements to this array as the cookbook runs, and eventually use that complete array as an input to the last recipe in the cookbook.

So as each recipe runs, I am trying to append to the attribute like this:

`node['tool_list'] << "tool:Python_2.7"`

which I do a few times for different tools, and then eventually cite in a resource in my final recipe:

```
resource "example" do
    labels          node['tool_list']
end
```

Except this doesn't seem to work and the final attribute appears to be blank. What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to append to the attribute like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really heavily not recommended. Arrays don't have any semantics for a layered merge so stuff gets weird really fast. A better approach is to use a hash and then use `node['tool_list'].keys` or something similar. Also you might be getting caught in a compile/converge discrepancy and need to wrap things for lazy evaluation (`lazy { node['tool_list'].keys }`).